# cloned repo of ionic app made with capacitor and unable to run ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, capacitor

i downloaded the ionic app from bitbucket similar platform to github, and now i am running ionic serve and it is not serving. instead it is giving error.

i have tried commanding ionic serve

```
$ ionic serve
> ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
Error: spawn ionic-app-scripts EACCES

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
MacBook-Pro:lcity apple$ ionic serve
> ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
Error: spawn ionic-app-scripts EACCES

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` before `ionic serve`?

Comment: Yes, i says found 0 vulnerabilities